# How can a Google Apps Marketplace Application retrieve the number of users on a specific domain?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

I am aware of the [Users list endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) in the Admin SDK Directory API.  However, it is really slow since you must iterate over all users to calculate the count.

I am also aware of the [currentNumberOfUsers endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/#retrieving_the_current_number_of_users_in_a_domain) in the Admin Settings API.  However, that API does not have a read-only scope, and it contains a lot of other potentially sensitive information.

Is there a read-only API for retrieving the current number of accounts on a domain?

Comment: Any thoughts on this issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451827/how-to-get-organisation-name-via-admin-sdk-apis-for-the-admin-user

Answer (score 1):

Users list endpoint is not that slow if you pass a "field" parameter instead of requesting all user data. A good "fields" value could be "users/primaryEmail".

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the count, you could actually just iterate through the userList

```
       Directory.Users.List userList = ...

        while (... ) {

            ...
            users = userList.execute();
            result += users.getUsers().size();
            ...
        }

        return result;
```