# How to get Organisation Name via Admin-SDK APIs for the admin user?

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

We want to use one of the Google API's Admin-SDK via OAuth2 access_token to get the Organization Name of the client who registers with our App from the Marketplace.
The documentation says, all I need to do is query the below URL to get Organization Name

http: // apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/general/organizationName

And as expected, we have set https: // apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/ as one of scope parameter

Can any one explain me how should I do this provided, I have access_token for the admin user who registered.

Should it be called as

https: // apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/general/organizationName?access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}

or

Should I pass some headers to it, to get the organisation name?

Is it possible to do this with Google APIs ? ( of the type www.googleapis.com/auth ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the newer, OAuth2-based APIs that is under https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users. You can either [GET](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) a user or [LIST/search](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users).